# ui router refresh crashes after exactly 6 clicks

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express, angular-ui-router

When the following steps occur, my application seems to break.

1. My code lets you click on a user, assign them a role, and then the page refreshes.
2. A separate GET request gets a list of all the users currently in the class.
3. After clicking on exactly 6 different people, my entire site ceases to work, and it won't let me go to another state.  All the information on the current page also disappears.

```
<div ng-controller="class" data-ng-init="getAllUsers()">
<div class="col-md-6">
    this is where all the users go
    <table ng-table="zz">
        <tr ng-repeat="user in $data |filter: { _class: '!' + classEdit  }">
            <td>
                <div class="radio">
                    <label><input type="radio" name="userN" ng-click="userId(user._id)">{{user.firstname}} {{user.lastname}}  </label>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <p>what type of account? </p>
        <div class="radio">
            <label><input type="radio" name="userRole" ng-model="userRole" value="teacher">Teacher</label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <label><input type="radio" name="userRole" ng-model="userRole" value="ta">ta</label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <label><input type="radio" name="userRole" ng-model="userRole" value="student">Student</label>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" ng-click="updateClass()" class="btn btn-info">Add To Class</a>
    </div>
```

```js
$scope.updateClass = function() {
  $state.transitionTo($state.current, $stateParams, { 
    reload: true, inherit: true, notify: true
  });
  $http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/updateClass',
    data: {userRole:$scope.userRole,
      userId:$scope.userUpdate,
      Id:$rootScope.classEdit
    }
  }).then(function(result) {

  });
};
```

If there's a better way to do the refresh, I'd be open to suggestions.

Comment: is there any errors in the console?

Comment: no, there are no errors in the console

Comment: could you create a plunker or something we could run and see the error?

Comment: I eventually figured it out.  Wasn't a ui thing, was sending http post requests in angular but not but not sending back anything.  Must be a security thing.

Comment: Please add your comment as an answer then accept in 2 days time. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually figured it out. Wasn't a ui thing, was sending http post requests in angular but not but not sending back anything.